# Any way to connect a device to my network switch if it has an IP on a different subnet?

Tags: networking, ping

I know two devices on a switch can’t talk if they’re on a different subnet (different network ID).
But, I’d like to know if there’s a “temporary way” to make them talk, so I tried adding a route to that device in my PCs routing table with unsuccessful result.

I tried adding it like this:
route ADD 192.168.210.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.233.43 METRIC 390
…where 192.168.210.0 is the network ID for the target device and .43 is my PC.
…I didn’t know what metric to put, so I tried several without success.

I wonder why this doesn’t work.  Ping returns Destination Host Unreachable.

I checked with Wireshark and the ARP request was successful, and the target device appeared in the arp -a table after the ping.

Is there any way to add a route so this works?

I’m using a PC and SOHO router.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Use IPv4 or IPv6 link-local addresses to talk between the two, if your router supports either of those. Or give your PC an IP address on the router's subnet (in addition to, not in place of, your PC's current IP addresses).

Comment: Have you considered VLANs?